# Android force layout update after Visibility.GONE

Tags: android

I'm trying to hide the bottom bar when the keyboard is up. I use a size change listener on the list view to detect changes. When the keyboard is up I set the bottom bar to Visibility.GONE. What I get is the center image, which has the bottom bar GONE, but the window not resized correctly. What I want is the right image, which has the text input right above the keyboard. I think it has to do with the window still resizing while I set visibility to GONE?

I'm open to any other solutions besides modifying the visibility, as long as when the keyboard is up the text input is right next to it.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <MyImageView
    android:id="@+id/topbar"
    style="@style/FillWidth"
    android:src="@drawable/topbar"/>
    <com.chess.genesis.MyListView
    android:id="@+id/msg_list"
    android:layout_below="@id/topbar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/input_box"/>
    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/input_box"
    android:layout_above="@+id/botbar">
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_msg"
        style="@style/FillWidth"
        android:layout_weight="82"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:maxLength="140"/>
        <com.chess.genesis.MyImageView
        android:id="@+id/submit_msg"
        style="@style/FillWidth"
        android:layout_weight="180"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rsubmit"/>
    </TableRow>
    <MyImageView
    android:id="@+id/botbar"
    style="@style/FillWidth"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/botbar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you are using relative layout then make use of android:alignparentbottom property

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [layout_alignWithParentIfMissing](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html) for your input box.

Comment: That still doesn't work. I think it might have to do when how I'm detecting the windows resize. I'm either setting visibility too early or late in the layout update cycle.

Comment: @Justin: You're right, it is too late: it seems that components are already measured. You can either set visibility during measure pass (I overrode onMeasure in the RelativeLayout [link](http://paste.org/pastebin/view/39806)) or use Handler to set it later starting another layout pass.